# Ubuntu 14.04 server went offline all of a sudden

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql, debian, rsyslog

I see the below in syslog, not sure what went wrong, any help will be appreciated. Is this beacause of an automatic kernel update as I see a new kernel version?

```
May 17 10:20:36 vps rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="456" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
May 17 10:20:36 vps rsyslogd-3003: invalid or yet-unknown config file command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' - have you forgotten to load a module? [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/3003 ]
May 17 10:20:36 vps rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104
May 17 10:20:36 vps rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
May 17 10:20:36 vps rsyslogd-2039: Could no open output pipe '/dev/xconsole': No such file or directory [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
May 17 10:20:37 vps /etc/init.d/mysql[534]: 160517 10:20:37 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
May 17 10:20:39 vps /etc/mysql/debian-start[969]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
May 17 10:20:39 vps /etc/mysql/debian-start[972]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
May 17 10:20:39 vps /etc/mysql/debian-start[972]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
May 17 10:20:39 vps /etc/mysql/debian-start[972]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
May 17 10:20:39 vps /etc/mysql/debian-start[972]: Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
May 17 10:20:39 vps /etc/mysql/debian-start[972]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
May 17 10:20:39 vps /etc/mysql/debian-start[972]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
May 17 10:20:39 vps /etc/mysql/debian-start[987]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have changed or removed debian users used to maintain MySQL.
'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/restore-debian-sys-maint-mysql-user/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.